How to make procedural textures seamless
In the image shown i have taken my character, added a producral scale shader, then I added a uv map, how do I get rid of the seams? I tried looking into triplanar mapping but it is very confusing and some explanation might help as the tutorials on youtube show with a texture based on an image while the one I use is based off shader nodes
I have redone the topology (not perfect I know is my first attempt), the uvs, and addeded the texture coordinate node linking the uv to vector but none of this has really led to much difference

[
[


Hello and welcome to BSE. There's not much info in your post so we can't really answer that. Perhaps add more details like how the mesh looks like and what the node setup looks like and perhaps the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

...or you just search for "blender seamless procedural textures" and voila -> first hit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwMwkUCe3KU

Hello could you please share your object? Or at least the material applied on the Suzanne's head?

I have added the mesh with uv maps, a link to the shader, and a screenshot of my current version of the shader

Let's address the elephant in the room. It doesn't seem like texturing is going to solve a lot of problems here. The topology of the character is not really suitable for many purposes at the moment. Maybe it would be better for you to seek feedback and advice on forums like Blenderartists.org . It's hard to recommend to spend a lot of time and effort on texturing when the character is not going to be very usable even if you put a lot of effort into it. You should work on the model first. When you have a good model, you can start thinking about a more serious texturing workflow.

Hello, @EmeliaFarraige.  While Martynas has straightforwardly expressed harsh truths about your problem, we can be confident that they don't constitute a personal  attack, at all. His  recommendations are good ones, and, I'm sure, they are intended to be taken at face-value, without a side-helping of insult. We are  trying to help, I promise :)

I think that UV mapping would solve it. You probably just need to add a Texture Coordinate node and connect its UV output to the Vector input on your Sc'les - BASE [Append] node. I can't test this theory, though, for I do not have your node group setups. EDIT: I just now noticed the seams on your mesh in the image. If you have done a UV unwrap since, that would explain why it isn't seamless. Here is an excerpt from the most recent Blender docs:

Just like in sewing, a seam is where the ends of the image/cloth are sewn together. In unwrapping, the UV map is discontinuous at the seams. Think of this method as peeling an orange or skinning an animal. You make a series of cuts in the skin, then peel it off. You could then flatten it out, applying some amount of stretching. These cuts are the same as seams.  [Bold/Italic added]

It is simply this: the seams on the mesh indicates a break in the UV. The UV simply doesn't loop around.
With one seam:

With two seams:

Here is the link if you want more info:  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/unwrapping/seams.html

sorry im kinda confused, what are you suggesting for me to do

Sorry if you are confused. All I can suggest is (assuming that the UV unwrap is the problem) to remap your UV's in way that they do not break off from each other. And creating the Texture Coordinate node and connecting it's UV output to your Vector input on the Sc'les - Base [APPEND] node. Hope this helps. Also, the answer by Benedicts Forester just might help.

Make sure your textures are unwrapped to the edges of UV editor. Unwrap in segments and make sure your unwrap ends perfectly at the edges of the unwrap window. Zoom in and use SHIFT + S > snap to pixels to further align with the window edge. Your texture ends at an edge and tiles further with that same edge so your unwrap has to be fitted perfectly to edges to be seamless

Hi sorry I'm confused on what you mean?
